# What is the $\mathbb{R}$-scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I want to study $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ in the category of $\mathbb{R}$-schemes.
I know that the structural morphism is derived from the ring morphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, which must be the inclusion. I also know that, geometrically, both $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}$ are just a single point, but I think that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-scheme is obtained after having two points glued together. How can I show this?

Comment: The fiber product $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{C}\otimes_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{R}}\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{C}$ is a disjoint union of two points (to see this, use the isomorphism $\mathbf{C}\simeq \mathbf{R}[T]/(T^2+1)$). In some sense, the single point splits into two when you base change to $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: @Sampah please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: it automatically produces the correct spacing with no need for other adjustments like your previous solution.